# TFS 2017 Run Functional Tests runs in OutOfMemoryException (no results saved)

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines

I have a test run that as around 280 tests. Of those 237 tests were executed (the rest skipped). The test is executed by Run Functional Tests and run on a single machine. After the run is completed.

But TFS never shows those results, because there is an OutOfMemory Exception. From the logs I assume this happens while transmitting the test results.

```
DTAExecutionHost.exe Error: 0 : ExecutionTaskStateModel.ExecuteTask: Recived error while executing task: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LimitMemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.JavaScriptUtils.WriteEscapedJavaScriptString(TextWriter writer, String s, Char delimiter, Boolean appendDelimiters, Boolean[] charEscapeFlags, StringEscapeHandling stringEscapeHandling, IArrayPool`1 bufferPool, Char[]& writeBuffer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.WriteEscapedString(String value, Boolean quote)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.WriteValue(String value)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteValue(JsonWriter writer, PrimitiveTypeCode typeCode, Object value)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializePrimitive(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonPrimitiveContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__17.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\Common\VssHttpMessageHandler.cs:line 206
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\Common\VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.cs:line 91
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__48.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\VssHttpClientBase.cs:line 818
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__45`1.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\VssHttpClientBase.cs:line 721
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__27`1.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\VssHttpClientBase.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__26`1.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\VssHttpClientBase.cs:line 0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LimitMemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.JavaScriptUtils.WriteEscapedJavaScriptString(TextWriter writer, String s, Char delimiter, Boolean appendDelimiters, Boolean[] charEscapeFlags, StringEscapeHandling stringEscapeHandling, IArrayPool`1 bufferPool, Char[]& writeBuffer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.WriteEscapedString(String value, Boolean quote)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.WriteValue(String value)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteValue(JsonWriter writer, PrimitiveTypeCode typeCode, Object value)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializePrimitive(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonPrimitiveContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__17.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\Common\VssHttpMessageHandler.cs:line 206
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\Common\VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.cs:line 91
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__48.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\VssHttpClientBase.cs:line 818
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__45`1.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\VssHttpClientBase.cs:line 721
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__27`1.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\VssHttpClientBase.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__26`1.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\VssHttpClientBase.cs:line 0<---
```

[Complete DTAExecutionHost.exe.log](https://gist.github.com/LokiMidgard/3dbcd19afb747dcdb2ba441aecffd0c9)

On TFS 2010 there was no problem with the size of the results.

### I'm currently not sure how to debug this further. All the test results are deleted after the cleanup.

Build Log:

```
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2472405Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test run is aborted. Logging details of the run logs.
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2472405Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]DistributedTests: Test run is aborted. Logging details of the run logs.
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2639752Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: New test run created.
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2639752Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]DistributedTests: New test run created.
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2639752Z Test Run queued for Project Collection Build Service (DefaultCollection).
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2639752Z 
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2639752Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test execution started. Test run id : 22452
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2639752Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]DistributedTests: Test execution started. Test run id : 22452
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2639752Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: UnExpected error occured during test execution. Try again.
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2639752Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]DistributedTests: UnExpected error occured during test execution. Try again.
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2639752Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Error : One or more errors occurred.--->Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2639752Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]DistributedTests: Error : One or more errors occurred.--->Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2639752Z 
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2639752Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test run aborted. Test run id: 22452
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2639752Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]DistributedTests: Test run aborted. Test run id: 22452
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2639752Z ##[error]System.Exception: The test run was aborted, failing the task.
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2639752Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]System.Exception: The test run was aborted, failing the task.
2017-09-12T09:12:46.2784911Z ##[debug]DistributedTests: Deleted test settings with id : 20637
2017-09-12T09:12:46.3097431Z ##[error]PowerShell script completed with 1 errors.
```

Comment: What's the detail error in your build log? And are you using the publish test result task in the build definition?

Comment: I added some more log, are those the logs you mean? I use the Distributed Test run. This one publishes the test results itself.

Comment: Sorry for the missing comment. Have your issue fixed? What's the Distributed Test run? Which test task are you using in the build definition? Are you using the Visual Studio Test task or Run Functional test task？ Could you separate your 280 tests to multiple test runs to see if the issue is still exist.

Comment: I have also opend a github [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/5304). But haven't got any feedback there (yet). There I have posted different things I tried. I have split the tests in 6 and reset the VM to an clean snapshot. This works. But costs almoast half an houre. I user Run Functional Tests Task.